# Can docker share memory and CPU between containers as needed?

Tags: memory, docker, virtualization, docker-compose

If I am running multiple docker containers with bursty memory and CPU utilization, will they be able to use the full capacity of the host machine?  Or will they be limited to their CPU and memory limits of the individual container definitions?

**For example:**

If I were running 3 containers that burst to 1GB of memory once per day, at disjoint times.

And similarly if those same containers instead were CPU heavy, and bursted to 1CPU unit per day at disjoint times.

Could I run those 3 containers on a box with only 1.1GB of memory, or 1.1 CPU unit respectively?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Docker containers are not VM's,
They run in a cage over the host OS kernel, so there's no hypervisor magic behind.

Processes running inside a container are not much different from host processes from a kernel point of view. They are just highly isolated.

Memory and cpu scheduling will be handled by the "host". What you set on docker settings are CPU shares, to give priority and bounds to some containers.

So yes, containers with sleeping processes won't consume much cpu/memory if the used memory is correctly freed after the processing spike, otherwise, that memory would be swapped out, with no much performance impact.

Instantiating a docker container will only consume memory resources. As long as no process is running, you will see zero cpu usage by it.

Comment: It makes sense for memory, and each of these would need to set their memory limit > 1GB.  If they all are using it, it will be swapped.  Everything is good with the world.

For CPU, the most fair allocation would be 1/3, 1/3, 1/3.  But, I guess what you're saying is the the CPU isn't a limit, it is a priority that only matters when CPU is contended. Right?

Comment: Swapping will kill your processes performance if they all try to run at the same time, otherwise there is no issue. Cpu shares only matter when the cpu is contended, but you have more complex scheduling policies if you need fine tunning. Check https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reviewing cgroups documentation, and actually docs for cgroups v2, since they are better structured that v1 docs. See chapter 5 for cpu and memory controllers: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt

Answer (score 0):

When you don't need to explicitly specify --memory and --cpu-shares option at the container startup, the container will have all the cpu share and memory available for use on the instance. If no other process is consuming the resources,then the container can use all the cpu and memory available.

In theory you should be able to run the 3 containers on the instance.
Make sure non of the containers tie up the memory or cpu resources.